# Javascript Reserved Words Eng

Tags: javascript

I have a div element in my page with id "eng". I then use a javascript function to restyle it onClick. (Specifically, hide) The function used the getElementById method. For some reason, it wouldn't work with id "eng" but when I changed it to "english" (this was the only change I made) it started working. Any idea why? I presume it's a reserved keyword, but couldn't find an reference to it.

Thanks!

Comment: show your code!

Comment: id's are just strings, you are free to use any word you want.

Comment: Are sure that, "eng" is used only once as id. Ids should be unique ( browser may tolerate multiple, but ... ). As for the reserved words [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) is a list of all of them.